# Set text color using if and else statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

SO i have this application that uses retrofit client to send a request to the ROS server and now my problem is that I am setting up my Status that if the status is "True" it will set to textcolor as GREEN and else as RED but when i execute it to my application it seems that its only executing the else statement it displays all red even if the status is true. Can anyone help me with this Im just a beginner.

Comment: best way is to create a static boolean in Application Class and then use it every where you want to set color

Comment: thanks for that. but how do i do that tho?

Comment: Yen Bico check answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't get the text of the SoftwareStatus , you need to get the text first convert it to string and then compare it if it is true .

```
if(SoftwareStatus.getText().toString().equals("true")) 
{
  SoftwareStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
} 
else 
{
SoftwareStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

It is because .equals() is usually used for comparing strings/characters/text

edited.

Comment: if this solves your problem kindly please mark it as an answer thanks .

Comment: you mean my method of softwarestatus which is the getSoftwareStatus(). nope it isn't yet in boolean. it returns string.

Comment: After reviewing your code it seems like getSoftwareStatus() is not returning "true" that is why in the logical statement it always ends up with else , I suggest your try to check the string that getSoftwareStatus() is returning in order for you to know if it is really returnin the desired string that you want .

Comment: it is returning the string that i want. my problem is that it does not terminate the whole if and else statement.

Answer (score 0):

`HardwareStatus` is a `TextView`, so it's always not equal to `false`. Maybe you want to check it text? In that case you should use `TextView.getText()` method

```
if (HardwareStatus.getText().equals("false")) {
    HardwareStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else {
    HardwareStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

And the first letter of variable should be lower case `HardwareStatus` => `hardwareStatus`

Comment: What is the value that you've set for the text view in this command:         `SoftwareStatus.setText(response.body().getSoftwareStatus());` ?

Comment: i have a method of getSoftwareStatus() that returns a string for the text view which is in the ObjectList class above.

Comment: I mean the real value that you have. Is it "true" or "false"?

Comment: this is a dynamic app so it depends on the status of the server that is giving but the value of the status from the server is giving either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Duy Khan Ngyuen answer is right, I just suggest you to use **equalsIgnoreCase**.

```
    if(HardwareStatus.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
        HardwareStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }else{
       HardwareStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
```

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase gives an error it says it cannot resolve that symbol

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add toString(). That code has been edited, You can try it now. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

after getting your response update your Boolean or string value in app class create  setter and getter for that then simply on before add check on your textView `

```
Class ApplicationClass extends Application(){

String statusValue="false";
Boolean statusBoolean=false;


public void updateStatusValue(String value){

this.statusValue=vale;
}

public String getStatusValue(){

return statusValue;
}


}
```

after calling API and getting response updateStatusValue

```
ApplicationClass.updateStatusValue(response.body().getHardwareStatus())



if(ApplicationClass.getStatusBoolean() ||Application.getStatusValue().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
SoftwareStatusTv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}else{
 HardwareStatusTv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

now you can add check for whole application using this simple getter setter